# How to best ask this question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I want to ask a question about the best way to visually highlight DOM elements a user is touching. However I am not having much luck on SO. Is it better on another forum, or is the way I am asking just wrong?

@Doorknob : Indeed the question in question : [stackoverflow.com/questions/15202472](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202472)

Comment: The question in question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202472/

Comment: Could you show how you are currently asking. Without that it is tricky to answer...

Comment: What do you mean by "best"? Best in a code compatibility sense? Best in terms of user experience? Best in terms of unicorn points you'll earn as a result?

Comment: Someone on the original Questions' comments had mentioned ux.stackexchange.com which deals with User Experience concerns, which it appears is what you are asking opinion about, try the question there if you haven't already

Comment: Hmm, initially thinking of unicorn points. But I don't care about code compatibility or old browsers. I just care about : UX, efficiency (since it is a mousemove), and must work across all kinds of web page colors and element types.

Comment: @curtisk Done, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For starters, this should be on https://ux.stackexchange.com/ since it seems to be a design question instead of a coding question.  Second, you need to define what your success metric is - an open ended "what's best?" question has no chance of being productive but you could rephrase as "which would be best at achieving X in situation Y?"

Comment: Cool thanks for the general framework of achieve X in situation Y. I'll use that for these types of questions from now on.